# NDSolve: "Stiff system" error returned instead of known smooth solution

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration

I tried to reproduce a known smooth analytical solution with NDSolve but only got

```
 NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 0.07416849521914343`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>
```

First I chose the integration region and the desirable solutions

```
rmin = 0; rmax = 10; tmin = 0; tmax = 20; 
solx[t_, r_] := Sin[t]*Cos[r] + 2
soly[t_, r_] := Cos[t]*Sin[r] + 2
```

Then I calculated the appropriate source terms

```
    sourcex[t_, r_] := 
 Cos[r]*Cos[
    t] + (Cos[r]^2*Cos[t]^2*Sin[r]*
     Sin[t])/((2 + Cos[t]*Sin[r])*(2 + Cos[r]*Sin[t])^3) + (2 + 
      Cos[t]*Sin[r])^2*(2 + Cos[r]*Sin[t])/(-0.5 + 
      Cos[r]*Cos[t]*Sin[r]*Sin[t])
sourcey[t_, 
  r_] := -Sin[r]*
   Sin[t] - (Cos[r]*Cos[t]*Sin[r]^2*
     Sin[t]^2)/((2 + Cos[t]*Sin[r])^3*(2 + Cos[r]*Sin[t])) + ((2 + 
       Cos[t]*Sin[r]) (2 + Cos[r]*Sin[t])^2)/(-0.5 + 
     Cos[r]*Cos[t]*Sin[r]*Sin[t])
```

so that the following first order PDE's system hold

```
system = {D[x[t, r], 
     t] == ((y[t, r]^2*x[t, r])/(
       D[y[t, r], r]*D[x[t, r], r] + 0.5) + (
       D[x[t, r], r]*D[y[t, r], r]^2)/(y[t, r]*x[t, r]^3)) + 
     sourcex[t, r], 
   D[y[t, r], 
     t] == ((x[t, r]^2*y[t, r])/(
       D[x[t, r], r]*D[y[t, r], r] + 0.5) + (
       D[y[t, r], r]*D[x[t, r], r]^2)/(x[t, r]*y[t, r]^3)) + 
     sourcey[t, r]};
```

along with the following boundary and initial conditions

```
    conditions = {x[tmin, r] == solx[tmin, r], 
   y[tmin, r] == soly[tmin, r], x[t, rmax] == solx[t, rmax], 
   y[t, rmax] == soly[t, rmax]};
```

I chose the following integration method

```
    mol[n_Integer, o_: "Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}
```

and called NDSolve

```
 sol = NDSolve[{system, conditions}, {x, y}, {t, tmin, tmax}, {r, rmin,
      rmax}, Method -> mol[61], 
    MaxSteps -> Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

The code collapsed after 177 secs at t=0.07. Neither fast, nor accurate.

The key problem here is that although the solution is fairly simple it must be the form of the equations that the code cannot handle. So how can one overcome this problem, if one is not able to tranform the PDE system to a simpler form? 
Can Mathematica and NDSolve in general handle such cases?

Comment: Have you solved this system with other numerical method? Can you add more background information? Where does this system come from? Are you testing `NDSolve` with kind of classical problem in certain area?

Comment: I used the Method of Manufactured Solutions to construct the above example.

Comment: This is merely my guess: you might have accidentally constructed an ill-posed problem i.e. _usual_ numeric method won't work well on the it even if analytic solution exists.

Comment: It is the first time I hear that a well-posed problem, with a definite analytical solution and sufficient initial-boundary conditions, can be numerically ill-posed! Have you got any bibliography on this?

Comment: The word "well-posed"/"ill-posed" is only used in numeric topics, AFAIK. One possible reference is the first 2 sections of this paper: http://math.nsc.ru/LBRT/u2/Survey%20paper.pdf

Comment: @student Before solving this system of equations numerically, it is necessary to bring it to a quasilinear form.

Comment: Ok, then I have to introduce some exatra variables?